# Debugging GNU octave: Using dbnext after dbup

Tags: matlab, debugging, octave

I'm using `GNU octave 3.6.4`. According to the [changelog (v 3.2)](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.2.html):

> Moving up and down the call stack with
>       dbup and dbdown now works.

However, when I'm in debug mode and excecute `dbup` followed by `dbnext`, the next line in the lower frame will be executed. Why is this so and how can it be avoided?

```
octave -q
 octave:1> myfunc_base(2,3)
 stopped in /home/seb/octave/myfunc.m at line 5
 5:   keyboard
 debug> dbstack
 stopped in:
   -->      myfunc at line 5 [/home/seb/octave/myfunc.m]
            myfunc_base at line 4 [/home/seb/octave/myfunc_base.m]
 debug> dbup
 stopped in myfunc_base at line 4 % <-- looks good!
 debug> dbnext
 stopped in /home/seb/octave/myfunc.m at line 6 % <-- damn this is the old frame!
 6:   sp = a + temp;
 debug>
```

The two test functions:

`myfunc.m`

```
function sp = myfunc (a, b, c)

  temp = b+c;
  keyboard
  sp = a + temp;

end
```

`myfunc_base.m`

```
function sp = myfunc_base (aa, bb)

  temp = myfunc(aa, aa, bb);
  sp = aa + temp;

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To step out you have to use `dbstep out`. This matches the behaviour of matlab and everything else would be very stange. You can not step to the next line on any level of the stack if an exception occurs.

Comment: ohhh. it seems I misunderstood `dbup`. I thought `dbup` was equivalent to gdb's `finish`. I'll test and get back. btw, I didn't understand your last sentence, could you clarify?

Comment: Assume a() calls b(), b() calls c(). Your line is in c and you use dbup, dbcont. During the remaining lines of c() an exception is thrown, where to jump if a catches the exception? There is no next line in b which is executed. Might be possible to implement somehow, but such a behaviour would be very confusing.